# attach pandas dataframe as excel file in email triggered from python

Tags: python, pandas, email

I have a pandas dataframe which is basically reult of a sql query.
I want attach as xlsx in an automated email triggered from python and that excel file should have the dataframe mentioned. How can this be done.

I am able to send the email without attachment successfully but not with the attachment.

```
import pandas as pd

data= pd.DataFrame(output of sqlquery) # this data is dataframe output of a sql query. 

# import necessary packages
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
# create message object instance
msg = MIMEMultipart()
password = "password"
msg['From'] = "xyz@gmail.com"
msg['To'] = "abc@gmail.com"
msg['Subject'] = "Messgae"
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
# Login Credentials for sending the mail
server.login(msg['From'], password)
server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
```

I dont want to attach the excel file from the file location. 
Firstly, have to write that dataframe into excel and then attach that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

fromaddr = '@gmail.com'
toaddr = ['@gmail.com', '@gmail.com', 
'@gmail.com']

msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = ", ".join(toaddr)
msg['Subject'] = "Hello"

body = "Sample Mail"

msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

filename = "Data.xlsx"
attachment = open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\file.xlsx", 
"rb")

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, "TYPEPASSWORD") #Type Password
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

Comment: For writing dataframe to excel -  data.to_excel('Data.xlsx')

Comment: This is great. So the file will be downloaded everytime i run  the script due to to_excel function. What if i want to attach it without saving it n the system ? Is there any other way ?

Comment: @Rajat Arora Glad it helped you , if it worked, can you pls accept this answer so as to close this question, thanks

Comment: Pls go through the link to know how to accept answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: can u pls accept the answer to close the issue - @Rajat Arora

Comment: Now I can sleep peacefully while keeping my google colab on running and can get output on my email.

Comment: Glad it helped you

Comment: As @RajatArora asked, is it possible to attach the dataframe as an excel file without saving the said file in the system?